# Dart fill ByteData with List<int>

Tags: dart, bytebuffer

```
List<int> l = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
var b = ByteData(10);
```

May I know what is the easiest way to fill `b` (position 4 ~ 7) with data from `l`.

I can certainly iterate through `l` and then fill `b` one by one. But this is just part of a larger solution. So I hope there is a simpler way (for easy maintenance in future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ByteData` represent an area of memory counted in bytes but does not tell us anything how we want to represent the data inside this block of memory.

Normally, we would use one of the specific data types from `dart:typed_data` like e.g. `Uint8List`, `Int8List`, `Uint16List` and so on which have a lot more functionality.

But you can easily get the same by making a view over your `ByteData`. In this example I guess you want to insert your numbers as `Uint8`:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  List<int> l = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
  var b = ByteData(10);
  var uInt8ListViewOverB = b.buffer.asUint8List();
  uInt8ListViewOverB.setAll(4, l);
  print(uInt8ListViewOverB); // [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
}
```

I recommend reading the documentation for the different methods on `ByteBuffer` (returned by `buffer`). You can e.g. make subview of a limited part of your `ByteData` if your `ByteData` needs to contain different types of data:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer/asUint8List.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. I use ``ByteData`` mainly because I need to use function like ``getInt32()``, ``setUint16()`` etc ... which is not available in ``List``

Comment: Yes, if your content is mixed data, the ByteData is a fine way to do it. Just create views when needed to see a chunck of this ByteData as a specific type. In my example, there are only the ByteData instance which I then manipulates through a view of the data.